# TaskAwaiter cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, async-await

I get a red line under my `await` in my code saying:
`The type arguments for method 'TaskAwaiter<TResult> System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter<TResult>(this Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation 1)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Though the code compiles and seems to work fine, I just wonder what this means? (English is not my first language, so I might just not understand the message)

```
private async void Init()
{
    var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(I2CAddress);
    settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

    var aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector(I2CControllerName);
    var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    _device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);
    _isInited = true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a error in the library you are using, the must be using some kind of custom awaiter.

Comment: What type is `DeviceInformation` and `l2cDevice`?

Comment: Okay, it might be worth mentioning that im running VS2015RC, so i guess it also could be a bug.

Comment: `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation`
`Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cDevice`

Guess its part of the new `Windows IoT Extension SDK`

Comment: I would create the smallest program possible that can recreate the error message and [submit it as a bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx)

Comment: Are you using Resharper?  There is some bugs in a version of that that could have caused this with VS2015RC.  Make sure you have latest.

Comment: Im using resharper, updated and it solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated resharper to latest version, solved issue